# Converting an event driven system to a non-even driven system

Tags: java, javascript, events, event-handling

We have an  event driven state machine in which some events are external ( from users of our system ) and internal ( our own code ).  To Simplify it I will use 2 acronyms IE (internal event) and EE (external event)

Algo:

```
IE-1: change state -> Running
Event IE-1 detected and action taken on event is authenticate.
IE-2: change state -> Authentication success
Event IE-2 detected and action on event is to send reply to client.
EE-3 client replies state -> Closed
Event IE-3 detected and action on event is to release all resources on server.
```

Now my suggestion is to replace all internal events into something like a template function and let the event handling be used only for EE. So new system would be :

```
template {

  change state to running.
  authenticate
  change state to auth success
  reply client
}

// Event trigger.

onEvent-closeConnection() {

}
```

Is this a right thing to do ? Any suggestions / feedback ? 
The primary purpose of the change is that system has grown so complex that is has become difficult to keep track of `sequence of control` flow just looking at the code. The event handling code is not in the same file as the action to be taken. This has made debugging harder. The template is an atomic operation.

Comment: What are the tradeoffs? For instance, why do you propose this change? What benefit does it have? Why would you not want to make this change? What benefits are there to staying with the current architecture? What happens if an EE occurs while you are authenticating? Or is the template an atomic operation?

Comment: As @TedHopp says, tradeoffs & benefits. Atomicity of "external authentication" or any external interactions are important to consider. External interactions may be better being at least partly tracked with their own columns in the database, rather than solely relying on a single state machine/ STATUS progressing.

Comment: @TedHopp the question has been updated. Please can I get some guidance considering why i need the way I need it ?

Comment: State machines are easy, it only gets complex when the number of states grows large (as it often does).  How complex/how many states do you have?  Why do I ask?  Because changing how you deal with the states might not be the issue, it might be how the problem is framed (the complexity).

Comment: @ChuckCottrill 6 states, but each state also is influenced by child states, got very complex and event drive has made it infeasible

Comment: State machines work well until you try handling child states (emulating language call/return semantics) or counting.  Ask yourself how you would revise the logic/control to be clearer.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill all said and done, i think my templates work better. Am I breaking any norm ? can you please try to answer my question ?

Comment: Chuck the whole thing, take a week of vacation, then ask yourself how you would do it as a new project today. Explain it to a rubber duck.